# "list index out of range" when opening abf. files using pyabf

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to open an abf (Axon Binary Format) using the pyabf library,
as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyabf
abf = 
pyabf.ABF(r"C:\temp\2018_07_02_06\2018_07_02_06.CH1.abf",loadData=True, 
          cacheStimulusFiles=False)
```

But I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-02884ab5af1b> in <module>()
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import pyabf
----> 5 abf = 
pyabf.ABF(r"C:\temp\2018_07_02_06\2018_07_02_06.CH1.abf",loadData=True, 
cacheStimulusFiles=False)
      6 

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyabf\abf.py in __init__(self, abfFilePath, 
loadData, cacheStimulusFiles)
     91             if self._preLoadData:
     92                 self._loadAndScaleData(fb)
---> 93                 self.setSweep(0)
     94 
     95     def __str__(self):

C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyabf\abf.py in setSweep(self, sweepNumber, 
channel, absoluteTime, baseline)
    486         self.sweepChannel = channel
    487         self.sweepUnitsY = self.adcUnits[channel]
--> 488         self.sweepUnitsC = self.dacUnits[channel]
    489         self.sweepUnitsX = "sec"
    490 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What should I do in order to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried starting the right side of the assignment on the same line?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, in the originial code it is on the same line, it was pushed down during re-writing it here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a format pyABF doesn't support for some reason - try sending your ABF to the pyABF author or open a GitHub issue and attach the file:
https://github.com/swharden/pyABF